# Building C# application with localization-aware language keys

Tags: c#, design-patterns, build, localization

**Intro**

I am looking for more customized solution for translating my app. I will be using `Humanizer` and `Smart.Format` *after* obtaining entries. The problem is to define keys to obtain them in the first place.

**Requirements**

The requirements are:

1. Language keys must be defined in-code, preferably near place where they are used
2. Language keys must contain default-English values
3. All language keys must be listed (XML, CSV, JSON, anything) ***after building the app suite***
4. Language entries must be provided from external source (like JSON file), without the need for any kind of recompilation
5. The app may contain multiple executables, shared libraries, etc. all of them in form of C# apps

**Discarded solutions**

First, the things I discarded:

- Built-in C# Resources.dll; They violate (1) and (4)
- External file with keys. Violates (1)

**My idea for handling the problem**

Now, my idea for the solution looks that way (and is inspired by C++ `GetText`)

There is a template class which contains keys:

```
private sealed class Module1Keys : LocalizationKeys<Module1Keys>
{
    public static readonly LocalizationKey HelloWorld = DefineKey("/foo", "Hello World!");
    public static readonly LocalizationKey HelloWorld2 = DefineKey("/bar", "Hello World2!");
}
```

And the class LocalizationKeys contains a static method that will actually register keys in simple collection

```
public abstract class LocalizationKeys<T> where T : LocalizationKeys<T>
{
    protected static LocalizationKey DefineKey(string path, string english)
    {
        var ret = new LocalizationKey(typeof(T), path, english);
        // Following registers localization key in runtime:
        Localization.Instance.RegisterLocalizableKey(ret);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

### Problem

The **only** thing left to handle in this approach is to *list localizable keys during build*... which is **where I had hit the wall**. It is very easy to list them during runtime, but I **cannot** run the code on *build time* (particularly it may be built as shared library).

Maybe I am overthinking myself and there is better, more clean solution - I don't need to stick with this solution, but Googling around has not yielded anything better...

Comment: @MickyD No, I do not want to use explicity `GetText` - if you got any better idea that still satisify #3 and #4, I will gladly accept. I cannot waiver either of that, unfortunately.

Comment: @MickyD Why voting for close? There is clearly stated problem to solve in last paragraph. And I shown my original research *after* stating the problem, so if you believe there is a better solution at all, I will gladly review that

Comment: @MickyD The code written is partial solution which I included to show my reserach. I cannot list the keys in build time (which is directly required by #3) I am looking to solve that.

Comment: Ohhhh you mean the **second** last paragraph.  Retracted.  Sorry about that good sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it. In `GetText` times we have to resort to manually parse code.

... but now, with CSharp, we have a Roslyn, with CodeAnalysis API.

## Solution

Wire up custom Console build tool that includes `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` NuGet and have code like:

```
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var methods = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

foreach(var method in methods)
{
    if(model.GetSymbolInfo(method).Symbol is IMethodSymbol symbol &&
        symbol.ContainingNamespace.Name == "MyProject" &&
        symbol.ContainingType.Name == "LocalizationKeys" &&
        symbol.Name == "DefineKey")
    {
        var key = method.ArgumentList.Arguments.FirstOrDefault();
        var eng = method.ArgumentList.Arguments.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

        if(key.Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax literalKey &&
            eng.Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax literalEng)
        {
            // "/foo" -> "Hello World!"
            // "/bar" -> "Hello World2!"
            Console.WriteLine(literalKey + " -> " + literalEng);
        }
        else
        {
            // Bonus: detect violation of key definition rule. It is not a literal!
        }
    }
}
```

Compile this Console tool as executable and add it as post-build step. Profit.